# Umbraco - Content Picker value for <a> tags

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, umbraco, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I am trying to use a content picker's value for a href in a partial view but I am struggling to get the format right...

I have been using

```
@(node.GetPropertyValue("propertyAlias"))
```

but when I use this in an  it just displays the ID of the node. How can I get it to give me the URL of the node?

```
<a href="@(node.GetPropertyValue("link"))">Link</a>



    @inherits Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoTemplatePage
    @{
        var items = CurrentPage.FirstChild("folder").Children("item").Where("Visible");

    }

    <div class="row tile-row">
        @foreach(var node in items)
        {
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="tile">
                    <h3>@(node.GetPropertyValue("itemTitle"))</h3>
                    @(node.GetPropertyValue("itemBodyText"))<br/>
                    @(node.getPropertyValue("itemButtonLink"))

<a class="btn btn-more" href="@(node.GetPropertyValue("itemeButtonLink"))">
   @(node.GetPropertyValue("itemButtonText"))
</a>            


                </div>  
            </div>
        }
    </div><!--/.row-->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get the Url of the item using the code below

```
<p>@Umbraco.NiceUrl(node.GetPropertyValue<int>("itemButtonLink"))</p>

<a href="@Umbraco.NiceUrl(node.GetPropertyValue<int>("itemButtonLink"))">
    @(node.GetPropertyValue("itemButtonText")
</a>
```

I hope this helps anyone else out who has been struggling with the same issue - Credit owed to - https://gist.github.com/tobbbe/7784542

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

`@Umbraco.NiceUrl(id of the node)`

of if you want the domain also:

`@Umbraco.NiceUrlWithDomain(id of the node)`

UPDATE:

```
@{
  if (Model.Content.HasValue("contentPicker")){
    var node = Umbraco.TypedContent(Model.Content.GetPropertyValue<int>("contentPicker"));
    <a href="@node.Url">@node.Name</a>
  }
}
```

Where `contentPicker` will be the property alias of your Content Picker Data Type.

Comment: Thanks for this - but i dont want to specify the id of the node I want it to bring in dynamic content. Can I do @Umbraco.NiceUrl(@(node.GetPropertyValue("linkAlias"))) ?

Comment: Hi Mivaweb - I have manged to get this working on a template but I can't seem to get it to work in my partial view - Can you help? I have added the code to my question. Thanks

Comment: So what I am doing is adding a folder to a page which contains some 'items' which have a title, body text and a button. Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi @Mivaweb - I managed to get this working in my partial view using the code above. Thanks for your help!